# How do I print rest-assured logs and log4j logs and/or system.out.println statements to a log4j file or text file?

Tags: log4j, rest-assured

How do I print rest-assured logs and log4j logs log.info and/or
system.out.println statements too to the log4j file? Current code
below only prints out the restassured logs but it is hard to read
which test case it belongs to and from which class. I was hoping 
someone can tell me how I can add that info in and get it to print out
the text comments I want to add to divide up the rest assured logs by 
tests and class. Thanks for your help.

```
package com.students.loggingexamples;

import com.student.base.TestBase;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Test;


public class LoggingResponseValues extends TestBase{

private static Logger log =        

LogManager.getLogger(LoggingResponseValues.class.getName());


 /*
 * This test will print out the response body.
 */

@Test
public void test003() {

    log.info("---Printing Response Body---");
    given()
        .param("programme", "Computer Science")
        .param("limit", 1)
        .when()
        .get("/list")
        .then()
        .log()
        .body()
        .statusCode(200);

}


/*
 * This test will print out the response in case of an error.
 */

@Test
public void test004() throws FileNotFoundException {
    log.info("---Printing Response Body In Case of An Error---");

    given()
        .param("programme", "Computer Science")
        .param("limit", -1)
        .when()
        .get("/list")
        .then()
        .log()
        .ifError();

}

}

public class TestBase {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() throws FileNotFoundException {
    RestAssured.baseURI="http://localhost";
    RestAssured.port=8080;
    RestAssured.basePath="/student";

    //Prints out the rest-assured logs into file
    PrintStream fileOutPutStream = new PrintStream(new 

    File("C:\\EclipseProjects\\students-application\\logs\\main.log"));
    RestAssured.config = RestAssured.config().logConfig(new 
    LogConfig().defaultStream(fileOutPutStream));

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use log4j-iostreams library to build a PrintOutputStream. Add that printStream to the RestAssured logConfig.